# Exchange 2010 Journaling email content

Tags: exchange-server, exchange-server-2010, journaling

I am using [journaling](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998649) on Exchange 2010 to get all emails passing hub transport in one mailbox. In those emails i get recipient, sender, subject and message-id. How would it be possible to get body?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing i need to do. Email received from journaling is email i need. It contains attachment, which is the original email, so i can get email body from it.